# How to get shipping rates in woocommerce rest api?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using [woocommerce-rest-api](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#) to create an app of woocommerce site. To create an order in store we have to use [create-order](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order) api, which requires basic all the order params. So there is a one params called `shipping_lines`, in which we have to pass shipping id, it's name and shipping rate. So before creating order I called api called [list-all-shipping-methods](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-shipping-methods) to displays all the shipping method and gives user to select shipping method, which will be pass later to create order. But the problem is that `list-all-shipping-methods` returning only `id`, `title`, `description` and `_links` parameters. It not returning the rate of shipping method which I need to pass on create order api.

Can anyone please help me how to get shipping rate so I can pass it to create order ?

Comment: Hi, were you lucky to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I have not found any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can get shipping details including cost by hitting:

`https://yourDomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/shipping/zones/ID/methods/ID`

but for this, you'll need `zoneID` and `methodId`

- For Zone ID
  `https://yourDomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/shipping/zones`
- For method ID `https://yourDomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/shipping/zones/<zoneID>/methods`

Now you have the desire zoneID and methodID:

`https://yourDomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/shipping/zones/<zoneID>/methods/<methodID>`

And if you want all the shipping methods with cost:

`https://yourDomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/shipping/zones/<zoneID>/methods`

> NOTE: You should configure shipping details first from your admin panel, otherwise you will not get the desire results.